Write a new sheet data in workbook with Pandas everytime script is ran
I would like Pandas to create a new sheet in an existing workbook every time the script is ran.
Below is the data that is being written
Is there a way to do this?
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(house_name,description_details,house_price,specs,ratings,cancellation_policy,urls),columns=['Property Name','Description','Price','Specifications','Ratings','Cancellation Policy','Link'])
df.to_excel(**File Path**)


Create a writer with ExcelWriter using Openpyxl as the engine in append mode, specifying a Sheet name each time.
This is all the code you need to create and write to a new Sheet in your existing Excel file.
sheet_name needs to be set to a new name each time the code is run with whatever method you are obtaining the name.
sheet = 'Sheet1'
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(house_name,description_details,house_price,specs,ratings,cancellation_policy,urls),columns=['Property Name','Description','Price','Specifications','Ratings','Cancellation Policy','Link'])

with pd.ExcelWriter(**File Path**, engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)


You can include if_sheet_exists param which can have these values {‘error’, ‘new’, ‘replace’, ‘overlay’}, default ‘error’ if you need to manage Sheet names that may be/get duplicated.

This option determines how to behave when trying to write to a sheet that already exists (append mode only).
error: raise a ValueError.
new: Create a new sheet, with a name determined by the engine.
replace: Delete the contents of the sheet before writing to it.
overlay: Write contents to the existing sheet without first removing, but possibly over top of, the existing contents.
If for example you are wanting to find the last Sheet name in the workbook so that you can continue a name or numbering scheme you can still use just the writer to do this;
After creating the writer;
writer.book is the workbook, writer.sheets[<sheet name>] is a worksheet with title <sheet name>, as Openpyxl objects.

In a scenario where your Sheets are named 'Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3' etc the following code example will get the last Sheet name, extract the number and create a new Sheet name in that sequence.
E.g. if the last Sheet was 'Sheet3' then the new Sheet name will be 'Sheet4'.
file_name = 'Numbers.xlsx'
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(house_name,description_details,house_price,specs,ratings,cancellation_policy,urls),columns=['Property Name','Description','Price','Specifications','Ratings','Cancellation Policy','Link'])

with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    ### Get last sheet number, add one and create new sheet name
    sheet = 'Sheet' + str(int(workbook.sheetnames[-1].replace('Sheet', ''))+1)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet)



You can use openpyxl along with pandas to achieve this.
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# new sheet DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(house_name,description_details,house_price,specs,ratings,cancellation_policy,urls),columns=['Property Name','Description','Price','Specifications','Ratings','Cancellation Policy','Link'])

# Path to the existing Excel file
file_path = '**File Path**\\existing_file.xlsx'

# Load the existing workbook
book = load_workbook(file_path)

# Create an Excel writer object and attach the existing workbook
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book

# Add a new sheet to the workbook and write the DataFrame to it
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='NewSheet', index=False)

# Save the workbook
writer.save()
writer.close()

Over here we are

Loading the existing workbook
Creating an excel writer object and attaching the existing workbook to it
Then we have added a new sheet to the workbook and written the DataFrame to it


It doesn't really make sense to load the workbook in Openpyxl first and use writer.book = book even in Pandas v1. Just create the writer as is in 'append' mode.
